# What are core files by Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image: Node Public Directory Listing]

As shown above, my newly installed Node.js application directory has a lot of *core.** files. What are these, and what is their purpose? Can I delete these files?

I installed Node.js behind [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) with *mod_proxy* that can use one of my domains on port 80. Then I installed [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever). Sometimes I have problems stopping Node.js with:

```
forever stop server.js
```

Maybe that is causing those dumps? Why are these appearing?

After all the problems found their answer, my VM's processes are limited to a given number. Node.js used with Apache seems to be the background.

```
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

Comment: It's in his app directory, not some lib directory somewhere on disk. He didn't create the file, he didn't install the file so it's a valid question to ask why the file is there in the first place. Not asking such questions will lead you to accept malware and viruses in your system.

Comment: Yea that's not normal if they are in your project file. To all the people that are downvoting his question, it's a question perfectly worth asking especially if it's in the app folder. fefe: Can you see any sub dir within the core dir?

Comment: I suddenly I see this files under my project folder and the number of theme is growing and I wonder what are they doing. Yes I tried to open the files but are coded

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting this interesting question?

Comment: [It began](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) as early as 2013.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`core.<number>` files are typically memory dumps created on Linux systems. The `<number>` is the Process ID of the process that crashed.

I guess your Node.JS application has crashed a number of times and these are the memory dumps left there for you to debug.

Comment: thanks this one should explain couple of thing. And how should I debug this crashes?

Comment: It is impossible to tell from the limited information given.

Comment: how to avoid to take these dumps by linux OS?

Answer (score 8):

Yea that's not normal if they are in your project file. To all the people that are downvoting his question, it's a question perfectly worth asking especially if it's in the app folder.

fefe: Can you see any sub dir within the core dir?

those look like memory dumps. So I guess you should be fine to delete them unless you want to go through them for debugging purposes.

Give this a try for debugging those crashes: https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler

Comment: thanks for the feedback I'm going to give a try with